# Service Stack Razor View Not Found

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I added the `RazorPlugin` along with a `Test.cshtml` in the root View folder (tried wwwroot as well along with `TestGet.cshtml`).  This is an donet Core project.  Whenever browsing to:  `/api/test` the following error is generated:

> Snapshot of TestGet generated by ServiceStack on 6/3/2017 4:20:40 PM
>   view json datasource from original url:
>   http://localhost:51550/api/test? in other formats: json xml csv jsv
>   Response Status Error CodeNullReferenceExceptionMessageObject
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.Stack Trace[TestGet:
>   6/3/2017 4:20:40 PM]: [REQUEST: {}] System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   ServiceStack.Mvc.RazorFormat.FindView(IEnumerable`1 viewNames) in
>   /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/d09206570215629/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/RazorFormat.cs:line
>   174 at ServiceStack.Mvc.RazorFormat.ProcessRequest(IRequest req,
>   IResponse res, Object dto) in
>   /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/d09206570215629/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/RazorFormat.cs:line
>   138 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate) at
>   ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequest req, Object
>   response, IResponse res) in
>   /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/d09206570215629/src/ServiceStack/Formats/HtmlFormat.cs:line
>   63Errors

The other formats work (json/etc).

```
 public class Test
 {
     public string ExternalId { get; set; }                
 }

  [Authenticate, Route("/test")]
  public class TestGet : IGet, IReturn<Test>
  {
  }

 public class TestService : Service
    {
        public IAutoQueryDb _autoQueryDb { get; set; }
        public IDbConnectionFactory _dbFactory { get; set; }

        public TestService(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory)
        {
            _dbFactory = dbFactory;
        }

        public Test Get(TestGet request)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            test.ExternalId = "abc";
            return test;
        }

    }
```

Test.cshtml

```
@using App.Shared.DomainModel
@model Test

<div>Test</div>
```

AppHost.cs

```
using App.DomainServices;
using App.FontEnd.Infrastructure.Configuration;
using App.FontEnd.Infrastructure.Core;
using App.Shared.DomainModel;
using Funq;
using LightInject;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Admin;
using ServiceStack.Api.Swagger;
using ServiceStack.Auth;
using ServiceStack.Caching;
using ServiceStack.Configuration;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.Mvc;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App.FrontEnd
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Base constructor requires a Name and Assembly where web service implementation is located
        /// </summary>
        public AppHost()
            : base("TestApi", typeof(CompanyService).GetAssembly())
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Application specific configuration
        /// This method should initialize any IoC resources utilized by your web service classes.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {


            this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
            {
                var currentSession = httpReq.GetSession();
                if (currentSession != null)
                {
                    RequestContext.Instance.Items.Add("CurrentUserName", currentSession.UserName);
                    RequestContext.Instance.Items.Add("CurrentUserId", currentSession.UserAuthId);
                }
            });

            ServiceContainer LightContainer = new ServiceContainer();

            LightContainer.RegisterInstance<IDbConnectionFactory>
            (
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
                    "removed",
                    SqlServer2014Dialect.Provider
                )
            );

            LightContainer.Register<IDbConnection>(c =>
                c.GetInstance<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection(),
                new PerScopeLifetime()
            );

            LightContainer.Register<OrmLiteAppSettings>(c =>
                new OrmLiteAppSettings(c.GetInstance<IDbConnectionFactory>()));           
            LightContainer.Register<ServiceStack.Web.IServiceGatewayFactory>(x => new ApiServiceGatewayFactory());
            container.Adapter = new LightInjectAdapter(LightContainer);

            var settings = LightContainer.GetInstance<OrmLiteAppSettings>();
            settings.InitSchema();
            AppSettings = new MultiAppSettings(
                settings
            );

            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new OrmLiteCacheClient
            {
                DbFactory = LightContainer.GetInstance<IDbConnectionFactory>()
            });
            var cacheclient = container.Resolve<ICacheClient>();
            cacheclient.InitSchema();

            AuthConfig(container, AppSettings);

            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowCredentials: true));
            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

            Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());



            OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) =>
            {
                var auditRow = row as CoreModel;
                if (auditRow != null)
                {
                    var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var insertUserId = RequestContext.Instance.Items["CurrentUserId"] as string;

                    auditRow.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    auditRow.CreatedDate = currentDate;
                    auditRow.CreatedBy = insertUserId;
                    auditRow.UpdatedDate = currentDate;
                    auditRow.UpdatedBy = insertUserId;
                }
            };

            OrmLiteConfig.UpdateFilter = (dbCmd, row) =>
            {
                var auditRow = row as CoreModel;

                if (auditRow != null)
                {
                    var updateUserId = RequestContext.Instance.Items["CurrentUserId"] as string;
                    auditRow.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    auditRow.UpdatedBy = updateUserId;
                }
            };

            var aq = new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100, EnableAutoQueryViewer = true };
            aq.ImplicitConventions.Add("%neq", aq.ImplicitConventions["%NotEqualTo"]);
            aq.ImplicitConventions.Add("%eq", "{Field} = {Value}");
            Plugins.Add(aq);
            Plugins.Add(new AdminFeature());

            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
                DebugMode = true
            });

            container.CheckAdapterFirst = true;

            //Set up service stack validators
            container.ValidatorsSetup();
        }

        public void AuthConfig(Container container, IAppSettings settings)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                    new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                    {
                        AuthKeyBase64 = "abcdefgh"
                    },

                    new BasicAuthProvider()
            }));



            var authRepo = CreateOrmLiteAuthRepo(container, settings);


        }

        private static IUserAuthRepository CreateOrmLiteAuthRepo(Container container, IAppSettings appSettings)
        {
            //Store User Data into the referenced SqlServer database
            container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
                new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

            //Use OrmLite DB Connection to persist the UserAuth and AuthProvider info
            var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>();
            //If using and RDBMS to persist UserAuth, we must create required tables
            if (appSettings.Get("RecreateAuthTables", false))
                authRepo.DropAndReCreateTables(); //Drop and re-create all Auth and registration tables
            else
                authRepo.InitSchema(); //Create only the missing tables

            return authRepo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request match the route and be at `/test`? and is the Razor View located at `/Views/TestGet.cshtml`?

Comment: Sorry it was registered as /api.  For instance /api/test.json returns fine. /api/test throws that error.

Comment: I updated my last comment (/api/test is where it lives).  Is there any debug logging to help me track this down?

Comment: What lives at `/api/test`? Please include the configuration you've used to be able to have it called from `/api/test`.

Comment: AppHost added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a minimal verifiable MVC test project to simulate your configuration which is working as expected at: https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/tree/master/src/RazorApi

It includes the [same Test Services](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/blob/76ed5baf23da23824918883cd6330bfefa323874/src/RazorApi/Startup.cs#L76-L93), (sans `[Authenticate]` attribute):

```
public class Test
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/test")]
public class TestGet : IGet, IReturn<Test>
{
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public Test Get(TestGet request)
    {
        var test = new Test { ExternalId = "abc" };
        return test;
    }
}
```

And the [minimal AppHost configuration](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/blob/master/src/RazorApi/Startup.cs) which just sets the `HandlerFactoryPath` to `api` and registers ServiceStack's `RazorFormat` plugin:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() 
        : base("ServiceStack + .NET Core", typeof(MyServices).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
            DebugMode = true,
        });

        Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
    }
}
```

With the `Test.cshtml` maintained in [/Views/Test.cshtml](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/blob/master/src/RazorApi/Views/Test.cshtml):

```
@model Test
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>Test.cshtml</h1>

<p>@Model.ExternalId</p>
```

Which works as expected with the Razor View executed when calling:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/test
```

Which also works when renamed to match the Request DTO at `TestGet.cshtml`.

As the issue seems specific to your project I'd compare your layout with bare [RazorApi Github Project](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/tree/master/src/RazorApi) to see if you can find any differences, failing that I'd recommend commenting out configuration to get it to a working state then uncomment sections at a time to find out which configuration is causing the issue.

Comment: I will comment out the configs and do some testing. Do you think it could be related to the light inject ?

Comment: @lucuma Not sure, also check that you don't have any [Startup Errors](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#startup-errors).

Comment: No startup errors and /api/requestlogs just show the error that I pasted into the question.  I'm going to start removing everything to see where it is failing.

Comment: After removing lightinject adapter which works fine in the project the razor plugin works.  It seems that the plugin doesn't work with adapters.  I can post the adapter code if you want but it is pretty simple.

Comment: @lucuma Is it just LightInject or it doesn't work with any IOC adapter?

Comment: I can't answer that, we use light inject and an adapter I wrote.  I'll try to add a different one tomorrow and test it.

Comment: I still haven't had time to test this with other adapters.